# Architectural term for places where water is used

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an architectural term for places where water is used? If you wanted waterproof flooring for rooms with faucets, drains, etc., it seems like there would be a term for such places so you wouldn't have to write "kitchen, bathroom(s), and other places where water is used" every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In designing school buildings, those areas which require special treatment because of the use of water (or other liquids, such as chemicals) are designated as **Wet areas**.

The same is true for [hospitals](http://www.boral.com.au/healthcare/wet_areas.asp).